# Trying to import requests package but getting pip error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-requests

I installed the requests package by downloading the code from GitHub and installing via command prompt in the usual way. However, attempting to import the module results in IDLE giving me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "requests.py", line 1
    pip install requests
```

I had installed pip awhile back by simply running the get-pip.py file in IDLE but had never used it so I'm a little surprised to see it pop up now. I tried installing requests using pip but I always get an invalid syntax error. Anyone have a clue as to what's going on here?
Thanks for the Help

**EDIT**: Right so what I'm doing is simply opening command line and typing pip install requests which results in me getting a message stating that requests is already installed (becuse I installed it using the setup.py file that was included in the GitHub distrubtion)

**EDIT 2**: Alright, so I just found my requests.py file and it only has one line..

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: How are you running this? Have you tried `pip install requests`?

Comment: Yea, I tried it in command prompt while in my E:\Python27 directory but got a syntax error. Same thing happens in IDLE

Comment: I don't understand- is the first line of your file `pip install requests`? (You are supposed to run `pip install requests` on the actual command line, *not* in a Python script or in IDLE)

Comment: Do you have a file called `requests.py` sitting somewhere?

Comment: Put a little more information in the edit, check it out if ya please. And I couldn't find a requests.py in my Lib folder, but I did find a requst.py? Am I looking in the right place? I assume I need to be checkin Lib/site-packages

Comment: rename / remove that file, and try to import requests again...

Comment: rename request to requests, you mean?

Comment: no, rename it to something like foobar as it clearly isn't the correct `requests.py`

Comment: You had another file with the name `requests.py` conflicting with the right one that python was trying to import first....

Comment: Hmm, strange because I renamed request not requests then it started working. The almost empty file is still named requests. Anyways, thanks

Comment: Did you check the sys.path before trying to import and see if request is located somewhere in this path?